# Placeholder Text Formatting

Tags: html, css

I have the following code.

```
<input class="domain" id="Domain" name="Domain" placeholder="Domain" required="required" type="text" value="" />
```

Im trying to format the placeholder text because it appears very small in the textbox, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: this isn't MVC related. It's CSS.

Answer (score 11):

Try this in your css

```
/*For Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) */

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   /* Your style here e.g. font size, color etc */
}

/* For Mozilla Firefox */

input:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Your style here e.g. font size, color etc */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The @Ilja answer including IE would be:

```
/* For IE browser */
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
   /* Your style here e.g. font size, color etc */
}

/*For Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) */
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   /* Your style here e.g. font size, color etc */
}

/* For Mozilla Firefox */
input:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Your style here e.g. font size, color etc */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about increasing the font size of the class domain to some legible font size ?

```
.domain
{
  font-size : 14px;
}
```

Comment: Main issue is that my text is aligned to top, i liked the ajaxtoolkit because the watermark automatically aligned my text, making the font-size bigger just ends up expanding the textbox :(

Comment: input::-webkit-input-placeholder  /* Safari Placeholder Style */
{
    color: Blue;    
}